# Enum implementing interface, interface and method visibility

Tags: java, interface, enums, package-private

I just came accross the following code, which surprised me a little bit, I converted it to a simple SSCEE here though:

**custompackage.package1.MyEnum.java**

```
public enum MyEnum implements MyInterface {
    CONSTANT_ONE() {
        @Override
        public void myMethod() {
            //do something very interesting
        }
    },
    CONSTANT_TWO() {
        @Override
        public void myMethod() {
            //do something very interesting
        }
    };
}

interface MyInterface {
    void myMethod();
}
```

Now from outside this package, I can do the following:

```
Consumer<MyEnum> myMethod = MyEnum::myMethod;
```

However I am not able to use `MyInterface` at all, which I understand as it is package-private to `custompackage.package1`.

I don't understand what exactly is going on though, it seems like `MyEnum` got the `myMethod()` method added, but it does not implement (from the outside) `MyInterface`.
How does this work?

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps the interface forces `MyEnum` to implement `myMethod()`, but then from the outside, any user of `MyEnum` simply sees that it happens to have a method named `myEnum()`, however the user knows nothing about the interface method that `myEnum()` is implementing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can't see `MyInterface` from outside the package, as you said - but `MyEnum` effectively has a public abstract `myMethod()` method, which you're able to use as a method reference.

Leaving aside fancy new Java 8 features, this is valid (even outside the package):

```
// Even MyEnum x = null; will compile, but obviously fail
MyEnum x = MyEnum.CONSTANT_ONE;
x.myMethod();
```

The method is inherited from the interface, even though the interface itself is not visible.

This isn't specific to interfaces and enums, either. For example:

```
// Foo.java
package foo;

class SuperFoo {
   public void publicMethod() {
   }
}

public class Foo extends SuperFoo {
}

// Bar.java
package bar;

import foo.Foo;

public class Bar {
    public void test() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.publicMethod();
    }
}
```

This compiles fine, even though `Foo` doesn't even override `publicMethod`. As far as `Bar` is concerned, it's inherited from *somewhere*, but it doesn't know where!

Comment: So Java was so nice to add the method to `MyEnum` as well as every constant is effectively implementing it?

Comment: @skiwi: Well it doesn't actually add it to the byte code as far as I can see - but it's implicitly there.

Comment: So that Java 8 method token is duck-typed?

Comment: @chrylis: No, it's using inheritance in the same way that the example I've shown does (it's able to call `publicMethod`).

Answer (score 1):

In interfaces methods are `public abstract` by default. fields are `public static final`

the reason you can use the method is that the interface is package local.  Try making it public.

Answer (score 1):

> However I am not able to use MyInterface at all, which I understand as it is package-private to custompackage.package1.

The interface is package-private, but all methods (and fields) are (implicitly or explicit) public.

> it seems like MyEnum got the myMethod() method added, but it does not implement (from the outside) MyInterface.

`MyEnum` has a public method called `myMethod()`, regardless of whether it inherited the (public) abstract method from the interface or whether it declared the method itself.  Said another way, even if the outside cannot see the interface, the outside can certainly see `MyEnum` and see `MyEnum.myMethod()`.